# Is it possible to access a Spring bean from Jruby

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jruby, javabeans

My goal is to create a way to simply create scripts to manipulate/populate my spring coupled database. I want to minimize code duplication and thus I want to access my data trough my spring DAO:s (Data access objects).

Becuase Java is suboptimal for scripting I was thinking that perhaps Jruby would be a better alternative. Thus I would like to access the Spring DAO beans trough the spring application context in Jruby.

My question is if this would be possible? and if any one knows of a tutorial that might help me.

So far I found this https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby , http://www.objectpartners.com/2010/08/23/gaining-access-to-the-spring-context-in-non-spring-managed-classes/

Answer (score 0):

Found a possible solution for you here:
http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/ruby/9780596155063/enterprise-java/applying_spring_aware_interfaces_to_jru